# Decorator does not add property to the class it is decorating. How do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, decorator

I am trying to understand how decorators work in javascript. I went through many articles regarding it but none of them actually explains the concept well.

I have tried the basic example of decorator from an article i have read. Here is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/ovpv/pen/wOZogV).
I have defined a decorator function called superhero. I am decorating my class "MySuperHero" with it. As per my knowledge, The decorator should add the property power to the class. but when i do console.log it shows undefined.

```
function superhero(target) {
  target.isSuperhero = true
  target.power = 'flight'
}

@superhero
class MySuperHero {

}

console.log(MySuperHero.power) // It should show "flight" but its showing undefined in console
```

Comment: FYI codepen editors doesn't support use of decorators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript natively doesn't support `@` decorators, you have to use `babel` please follow the installation steps mentioned in link: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators

Answer (score 1):

You should use `babel --optional es7.decorators` (babel CLI) to enable decorators.
As it is still a proposal more info could be found [here](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/).

Hope this helps!